# Connect to SFTP with .ppk private key in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, sftp

I'm trying to connect from CodeIgniter to SFTP server. But this SFTP uses a private key with a .ppk extension.

The general code is

```
$sftp_config['hostname'] = 'your.sftp-domain.com';
$sftp_config['username'] = 'your_sftp_username';
$sftp_config['password'] = 'your_sftp_password';
$sftp_config['debug'] = TRUE;`
```

How about config using private key?

Full code example using private key to connect on SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know CodeIgniter. And briefly checking it, it actually do not seem to support SFTP out-of-the-box. You must be using some 3rd party plugin. And chances are that the plugin does not support PPK keys, as that's a proprietary format of PuTTY client.

Anyway, it's not true that *"this sftp uses a private key with a .ppk extension"*. The *server* does not care, what format of the key you use *locally*. So just covert the key to the format that your *local* SFTP client *library* supports. That's most probably the OpenSSH format. Use PuTTYgen to covert the key.